# Assembly- Pass and retrieve a string pointer in a function

Tags: assembly, x86, compiler-construction

I'm working on a compiler (just a fun hobby project). My compiler implements a custom language pretty similar to C (mainly in that its portable assembler), and generates x86 assembly code which I build using NASM. Currently, I'm working on implementing passing strings to a function, and I'm pretty stuck. Specifically, I'm trying to pass a string and assign it to another string (the function argument right now). Here's what my program is trying to compile:

```
# Test passing a string

func print_str(s:str)
    println("Your string is:")
    println(s)
end

func main
    #str s = "Hello!"
    print_str("Hello!")
end
```

And here's the assembly it generates:

```
section .data
    print_str_s db "",0
    chr_fmt db "%c",10,0
    int_fmt db "%d",10,0
    str_fmt db "%s",10,0
    flt_fmt db "%f",10,0
    STR_1 db "Your string is:",0
    STR_2 db "Hello!",0

section .text
    global print_str
    extern printf
    global main

print_str:
    mov eax, [esp+8]
    mov [print_str_s], eax

    push eax
    push dword STR_1
    push dword str_fmt
    call printf
    add esp, 12

    push eax
    push dword print_str_s
    push dword str_fmt
    call printf
    add esp, 12

    ret

main:
    push dword STR_2
    call print_str

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

I consider this the best so far because it doesn't segfault, and at least prints garabage. The second best I was able to do was to use the movsb instruction in a similar way as described here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Data_Transfer#Move_String. A solution that's applicable to other arrays would be nice. I feel like I'm on the right track, but I don't know.

Strings are newer territory for me in Assembly; my compiler currently can pass integer and floating-point arguments, do conditionals, loops, external function calls, and few other things, so I feel like I have a fairly good knowledge of assembly.

Hopefully this makes sense. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Normally you don't actually copy the data, you just pass a copy of a *pointer* to the string.  So `movsb` is not useful for implementing a C-like calling convention for strings.

Comment: I realize that, I mentioned it because it at least didn't blow up with that method :) But yes, I'm basically trying to pass the pointer and re-assign it.

Comment: You know EAX is call-clobbered, right?  So the 2nd `push eax` is pushing the return value of the first `printf`.   (Function calls are also allowed to destroy ECX and EDX without saving them.)  IDK why you're passing a 3rd arg to printf that the format string won't cause it to look at.

Comment: I do know that eax is used for that, as my compiler supports returns. The code that generates the printf is pretty much cobbled together; I got it from another source (with a few modifications), and I plan to replace it later on.

Comment: I just noticed you have `mov [print_str_s], eax` which stores 4 bytes, overwriting the one zero byte from `db "",0` and the `"%c",10` in the next format string.  That's weird.  If you want a buffer to store a string into, make it larger than one byte.  e.g. `times 10 db 0`.  Or `push eax` to put it in stack memory then push a pointer to that (`push esp`).

Comment: its a good idea to use or start with an existing calling convention.  Or at least use it as a reference then make your own from that.  so put the string in .rodata and pass a pointer to it.

Comment: I think the `mov eax, [esp+8]` should use a +4 displacement instead.

Comment: And `mov [print_str_s], eax` overwrites *chr_fmt*. And you put a pointer into that variable *print_str_s* then refer to the address of the variable, where you want to push the contents instead, ie `push dword [print_str_s]`.

Comment: @ecm Your second comment worked... I see why too thanks a ton.

Comment: The first part of ecm's comment is also a bug; the only reason you didn't need to fix it is that you don't use `chr_fmt` so it's ok to destroy it.